# How can the datagridview directly after assign a value in code?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a WinForms application and i use datagridview in form. The DataGridView have many checkbox columns and the cells can be selected and processed by code.

So it's possible to check/uncheck all cells or copy to/insert from clipboard. This works fine except the last selected checkbox. 1st value is not shown as long as the cell is selected.

I have tried to set `SuspendLayout`, `Refresh`, `Update` and then `ResumeLayout`. But any one of them does not work for me.

```cs
private void SetCheckBoxCells(bool value)
{
  myDataGridView.SuspendLayout();

  foreach (var cell in myDataGridView.SelectedCells)
  {
    (cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = value;
  }

  myDataGridView.Refresh();
  myDataGridView.Update();         
  myDataGridView.ResumeLayout();
}
```

I expect that all cells are visually set/unset after click on the menu entry, but the last one is visually set after deselect the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is almost certainly not caused by the `Refresh`/`Update`. If that was a problem, you'd see a correct value after first manual edit in other cell. You **can also check the value**, i.e. simply:

```
MSgbox(myDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value.ToString);
```

Obviously, with correct indexes. I'm sure you'll get what you see, though.

`foreach` in `SelectedCells` should be pretty robust and does not suffer from index error, so I would double check, whether a `CellEdit` state, or `CurrentCell` focus or some event does not interfere with the first cell, preventing it to be updated.

Perhaps try setting current cell to something outside the selected range:

```
myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0];
    // some other cell not included in selection
```

What the integers (x1 to y2) are doing there? They're not employed. Just left from testing? Try to address the troublesome cell directly (just for debugging), simply like that:

```
myDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0].value = True
```

Obviously with correct indexes. Perhaps it will tell a bit more about the problem.

Comment: Tanks a lot! The x1 to y2 integers in my question are not needed here so I've deleted them. So that works (selecting a cell outer `SelectedCells`). Afterwards I set the `CurrentCell` at the first cell prior this again.  `myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[myDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1];
            myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView.Rows[y2].Cells[x2];`